# Link Docker Container to Volumes

Tags: php, mysql, docker, amazon-ec2, drupal

I currently have a codebase for Drupal using Drupal-VM vagrant box and VirtualBox. I would like to migrate to docker but I am unaware on how to integrate it with my existing code base.

Can anyone help me? I have followed instructions from [Docker Hub - Drupal Install Steps](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal) and [MySQL and Drupal Container](https://www.mikestiv.com/blog/running-drupal-docker) to spin up mysql and Drupal images but how do I make it point to my pre-existing codebase?

---

Previous posts with more Details, Questions and Background:

- [Migrate Drupal Local Environment to Docker/Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65147301/migrate-drupal-local-environment-to-docker-container)
- [Drupal Local Development Setup/Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129883/drupal-local-development-setup-environment)

Answer (score -1):

after spinning up the docker container you can copy the existing code to the container using `docker cp` [docker cp docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

as far as the database you can just import it to the mysql container

to link the container to a volume use the `-v` flag when starting the container

Comment: Im unsure on what you mean. Can you provide the steps so that I can try it on my end to see if it works or not?

Comment: for me i would create a container using ```docker run --name [container name] --link [mysql container]:mysql -v [volume name]:/var/www -dit drupal``` then from the host you can copy your existing files to the container with ```docker cp [site-dir] [container name]:/var/www```

Comment: You may have to do some nginx/apache config within the container to make sure that it points to the new files correctly